# Bond lengths in P₄O₁₀

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, pnictogen

According to JD Lee's *Concise Inorganic Chemistry*:

> The double bond $\ce{P=O}$ in $\ce{P4O10}$ contains p(π)–d(π) backbonding, where a full p-orbital on oxygen overlaps with an empty d-orbital on $\ce{P}$.

The four oxygens around each $\ce{P}$ form a tetrahedral shape. Then one lone pair from  $\ce{P}$ in it's $\mathrm{sp^3}$ orbital will donate to an empty p-orbital on $\ce{O}$ (created by pairing of electrons in it's remaining two p-orbitals), only then can the "doubly-bonded" oxygen attain it's octet. There is no "single electron from each" bond here. Is my understanding correct?

In earlier similar questions ([Hybridisation of POCl3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66344/hybridisation-of-pocl3)) and ([Bonding in the phosphate ion](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13657/bonding-in-the-phosphate-ion)) the d-orbital theory has been said to be disproven, but then how do you explain the different bond lengths in the double (1.43 Å) and single (1.65 Å) $\ce{P-O}$ bonds?